# How to stop app name from appearing in Open Graph story attachment

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've created a custom action and a custom service and I have configured the 4 caption lines in the edit attachment screen. The problem I have is that og:title always appears by default (which is OK for me) but also my app name appears on the 2nd line - which is really undesirable. This wasn't happening a week ago and I can't work out why it's suddenly doing it now or how to prevent it.

I submitted a bug to Facebook and the response was that it's by design but it wasn't always doing it so it must be controllable. Has anybody else come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of this is strange but it turned out that once my app was submitted for review and approved the app name no longer appears in the attachment. However, in the mobile FB app view it still shows the app name and doesn't show the lines as defined in the attachment. I guess this is just a difference between the UI design of web and mobile.

Comment: I experience the same problem! Have you gotten any resolution?

Comment: Facebook have confirmed that it's a bug but they haven't given me a timescale for resolution. See this link http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/234212296756903.